# C / JSON Library in popular Linux distros?

Tags: c, linux, json

I have a program written in C that has to input and output JSON over a local domain socket. I've found several C / JSON libraries that 'almost work' through searches. Prior to taking one of the libraries that I found .. I want to be sure that I'm not over-looking a library that is commonly found on modern Linux distros.

I'd also really appreciate links to libraries that you use. Most likely, I'll just drop it in tree, unless I realize that I've over looked something widely distributed.

I am tagging this as subjective because the answer that I select is the one linking to a library that works for me, that does not mean its the 'best' library.

I want to take an existing array and easily convert it to a buffer that can be sent, or take a buffer and easily convert it into an allocated array.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you tell us what you've tried, and why it's unacceptable. Making us guess what you have and haven't ruled out is just a waste of time.

Comment: @Matthew, I am not going to label the work others have released as unacceptable on a popular programming site. The compromise was to list what I wanted it to do. Obviously, if what I tried did what I asked for, I would not have posted the question :)

Comment: I don't consider it an insult against developers to say a framework is unacceptable for you.  That doesn't necessarily mean it's bad code, or that it isn't useful for someone else, just that it can't fit in your circumstances.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[json-Glib](http://live.gnome.org/JsonGlib) seems to be in the repositories for most distributions, I have not used it, so I cant speak as to its quality or stability.

Comment: Yes, it seems hard to find a modern distro that lacks it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I'm not too much into C, but, MJSON just reached 1.0 ( http://sourceforge.net/projects/mjson/ ), and also, another recently updated project is json-c ( http://oss.metaparadigm.com/json-c/ )...